# Legality of Termination

Tags: termination, legal

I am assuming that in any American corporation, either the employer or employee can terminate their relationship at any time. Here are questions that I have:

> 1. Is it legal for a company to terminate an employee because they have a "bad personality" (e.g. too shy and quiet)?
> 2. Is it legal for a company to terminate an employee for no reason at all? For example, in two days Company X tells an employee that he is
>      terminated without giving a reason and no notice period. If this is
>      the case, then why don't companies do this more often?
> 3. Is it just a myth that employees "sleep their way to the top"? For example suppose employee A has a good friendship with his (includes her also) boss but does poor quality work. Employee B has a professional and less friendly relationship with his boss but does amazing work. If (2) is true, then can the boss can still terminate Employee B?

**Edit 1** In my definition "sleeping their way to the top" comes in degrees: (i) being friendly with your boss, knowing about their personal life, etc.. and (ii) having a sexual relationship with your boss

**Edit 2** Also having a professional relationship with your boss means that you are just polite and talk about work and nothing personal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what "sleep their way to the top" means.

Comment: @AffableAmbler: I meant it in degrees: (i) being friendly with your boss, knowing about their personal life, etc.. and (ii) having a sexual relationship with your boss.

Comment: You need to add option 4 : "Having the correct school tie"... And inspite of your username I take you aren't...

Comment: I'll answer the question that OP is desperately trying to phrase in his favour- in an at will state, yes your boss can fire you because you accused her of sleeping her way to the top.

Answer (score 6):

> I am assuming that in any American corporation, either the employer or
>   employee can terminate their relationship at any time.

In an at-will state, that is generally true, with some exceptions. An employer can dismiss a worker without just cause.

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment

> Is it legal for a company to terminate an employee because they have a
>   "bad personality" (e.g. too shy and quiet)?

Yes it is legal.

It's more likely to happen in cases where the job role demands interaction with the public and where a "shy and quiet" personality would be a distinct disadvantage, such as a sales role. It's less likely where such shyness isn't as significant, such as a programmer.

> Is it legal for a company to terminate an employee for no reason at
>   all? For example, in two days Company X tells an employee that he is
>   terminated without giving a reason and no notice period. If this is
>   the case, then why don't companies do this more often?

Yes it is legal, although rare in my experience.

It's not done more often because most companies are reasonable and like to give a reason when dismissing an employee. Sometimes the reason involves generalities like "bad fit". In most cases of dismissal, it's not hard for a company to come up with reasons, even if they are not legally required to do so.

> Is it just a myth that employees "sleep their way to the top"?

In general, it is a myth. It happens sometimes in very small companies; less so in larger companies. Overall, it would be a poor way to navigate your career. Blaming your lack of progress on others "sleeping their way to the top" is mostly likely just kidding yourself.

> For example suppose employee A has a good friendship with his
>   (includes her also) boss but does poor quality work. Employee B has a
>   professional and less friendly relationship with his boss but does
>   amazing work. If (2) is true, then can the boss can still terminate
>   Employee B?

Friendship helps but usually cannot overcome incompetence. Best is to produce amazing work and be friendly with everyone.

Yes, the boss can still legally terminate anyone.

Comment: In addition - It's potentially expensive for companies to terminate employees without *cause*. If you're not fired for violating company policies / etc, something that would really require you to be fired, a frivolous termination means that employee will qualify for Unemployment insurance benefits thru the government; This raises the companies Unemployment insurance premiums for other / future employees, making terminations expensive for the company, along with the risk of liability thru potential Wrongful Termination lawsuits (even if they're unsuccessful)

Comment: A company will always have a reason for terminating an employee. Hiring an employee comes with a cost, having to fire an employee, requires that employee to be replaced potentially.  A company might keep their reasons for terminating an employee to themselfs for a varity of legal reasons.  At the point of terminating an employee, the employee/employer relationship typically isn't very good, so it doesn't do anyone good to provide a bunch of reasons (typically negative) to an employee heading out the door.

Answer (score 0):

**As you have, I'm going to assume a company operating in the "average" American state.**

> Is it legal for a company to terminate an employee because they have a
>   "bad personality" (e.g. too shy and quiet)?

**Yes.**

> Is it legal for a company to terminate an employee for no reason at
>   all?

**Yes,** though they would probably want to provide a reason to help avoid accusations of the underlying reason being illegal.

> Is it just a myth that employees "sleep their way to the top"? For
>   example suppose employee A has a good friendship with his (includes
>   her also) boss but does poor quality work. Employee B has a
>   professional and less friendly relationship with his boss but does
>   amazing work. If (2) is true, then can the boss can still terminate
>   Employee B?

**Yes.** Nepotism is not illegal. There may be factors that may change the situation. For instance, if you reject your boss's advances, and you are fired because of it. A company is not obliged, by law, to make the best decisions for the business.